# GSONRequest sends empty JSON?

Tags: android, json, gson, android-volley

I have an android application trying to send a POST request to my python server. I am using the Volley `GSONRequest-class`. Currently I am trying to send a user like this `{"username": "xxx", "password": "yyy", "email": "zzz"}`, but the server receives a Nonetype `JSONObject`, resulting in an error 500.

I am very confused as to why the post request sends an empty JSON since the print i made in the `getBody()`-method shows this:

```
{"username": "xxx", "password": "yyy", "email": "zzz"}
```

which doesn't look like a NoneType to me. My question is therefore; Where in `GSONRequest` do the dataIn disappear?

MainActivity:

```
    package com.example.adrian.testgsonbango;

        import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.EditText;

        import com.android.volley.Cache;
        import com.android.volley.Network;
        import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
        import com.android.volley.Response;
        import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
        import com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork;
        import com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache;
        import com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack;
        import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

        import java.util.HashMap;
        import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void postEvent(View v) {
        EditText userField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userField);
        EditText pwField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordField);
        EditText emailField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailfield);
        String user = userField.getText().toString();
        String pw = pwField.getText().toString();
        String email = emailField.getText().toString();
        User u = new User(user,pw,email);
        GsonRequest<String> req = new GsonRequest<>("http://python-cicero-app.apps.ida.liu.se/user", u, String.class, null, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                System.out.println("post succesful!");
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {}
        });

        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue()
    {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            Cache cache = new DiskBasedCache(this.getCacheDir(), 20 * 1024 * 1024);
            Network network = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());
            mRequestQueue = new RequestQueue(cache, network);
            mRequestQueue.start();
        }
        return mRequestQueue;

    }
}
```

GSONRequest:

```
package com.example.adrian.testgsonbango;


import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.NetworkResponse;
import com.android.volley.ParseError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpHeaderParser;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Map;

public class GsonRequest<T> extends Request<T> {
    private final Gson gson = new Gson();
    private final Class<T> clazz;
    private final Map<String, String> headers;
    private final Response.Listener<T> listener;
    private final Object dataIn;

    /**
     * Make a GET request and return a parsed object from JSON.
     *
     * @param url URL of the request to make
     * @param clazz Relevant class object, for Gson's reflection
     * @param headers Map of request headers
     */
    public GsonRequest(String url, Object dataIn, Class<T> clazz, Map<String, String> headers,
                       Response.Listener<T> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(Method.POST, url, errorListener);
        this.dataIn = dataIn;
        this.clazz = clazz;
        this.headers = headers;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        return headers != null ? headers : super.getHeaders();
    }

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(T response) {
        listener.onResponse(response);
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
        System.out.println("gson: " + gson.toJson(dataIn));
        return gson.toJson(dataIn).getBytes();
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<T> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        try {
            String json = new String(
                    response.data,
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
            System.out.println("JSON: " + json);

            return Response.success(
                    gson.fromJson(json, clazz),
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        }
    }
}
```

User:

```
package com.example.adrian.testgsonbango;

/**
 * Created by Adrian on 2017-04-24.
 */

public class User {
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String email;

    public void setName(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getUsername() {

        return username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public User(String username, String password, String email) {

        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "username='" + username + '\'' +
                ", password='" + password + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check the body content type?

Comment: Yes i found this to be the problem! You are absolutely right. One must override the getBodyContentType()-method and make it return "application/json". This did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

As Krish stated in his comment, what fixed the issue was to override the getBodyContentType()-method in GSONRequest and make it return "application/json", see below:

```
@Override
    public String getBodyContentType() {
        return "application/json";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

500 error means internal server error It happen when server unable to process your request due to invalid data or error on server side while executing request , So must check server code and the data your sending is in correct form or not.